# Reducing 3 SAT to 3 SET PACKING

Tags: np-complete, reductions, np-hard, np, packing

I'm trying to prove NP-hardness of 3 SET PACKING, which is a following problem: given a family of sets where each set contains 3 elements, decide whether the family contains k sets that are pairwise disjoint.

I tried reducing 3 SAT, but to now avail, but reduction of any other NP-complete problem would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is known as [3-dimensional matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-dimensional_matching), or 3DM. It is one of the 21 problems proved to be NP-hard in [Karp's original paper](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~luca/cs172/karp.pdf) (number 17 on his list).